# Rotate css3 bug

Tags: css, transform

I'm making a 3d cube based on http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/
but mine react on mouse event and touch event on mobile.

I introduce RotateZ to evitate the strange behaviour of the original Hayes cube.

But when if i try to go left -> down and left again it bug.

```
   -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

RotateX and Z make move cube on the same axis I don't know why.

Does it a bug or there is a solution ?

here's is a detailled jsfiddle of my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/uq2cr/6/

Thank's for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

This is because when you move the mouse up/down, whilst moving left/right and clicking it will reside to the up/down action.

**Current Strucutre**

I benchmarked the update of x co-ords.

[image: Right Click / xMove]

For both left and right directions, **x 0**, doesn't seem relative.

The **xAngle, yAngle, zAngle** increment, but do not reset to 0.

**Suggestion**

I suggest making some changes to the structure of **cubePointerMove()**. Make each direction their own stack. That way, there will be no forthcoming problems with the 4 directions.

The way it's set out now, is with duplicate up/down actions in the left/right blocks.

*Current*

---

```
// Left
if( xMove < 0) {
  // Up
  if( yMove < 0 ) {
    if(xMove < yMove){
    }
  }
  // Down
  else {
  }
}
// Right
else
{
}
```

*Revised*

---

```
// Up
if( yMove < 0 ) {
}
// Down
else {
}
// Left
if( xMove < 0) {
}
// Right
else {
}
```

Comment: I, thank's to take the time to answer my question ! But do you test -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg); this position of the cube ? After if you try to move the rotateX or Z value manually with the chrome element explorer the cube move vertically in both cases... It must not be...

Comment: I was testing in Chrome. For this to work in Internet Explorer and Firefox, you'll need `transform: rotateX();`

Comment: Im under chrome for now it's not a problem of browser compatibility for me. If your modif works for you just could you send me the jsfiddle updated and working to make the test, make sure we understand ?